# Include Sidebar Generator plug-in into my WP theme

Tags: include, wordpress, sidebar

I'm trying to include this plug-in:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sidebar-generator/

Into my wordpress  theme. As many people around the internet said, I just included the sidebar_generator.php file into my functions.php. The 'Sidebars' menu appears under appearance, but  no matter what I do, If I click on it nothing happens (just like it was linked on a '#').

If I install the plug-in through the wordpress interface everything works, I need to have it integrated though.

Any help?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need a plugin to have extra sidebars. You should be able to build a theme template with as many sidebars as you want. When I'm creating a custom theme in WordPress I use a variation of the [960 CSS Grid](http://960.gs/) (another good one is the newer [1140px CSS Grid System](http://cssgrid.net/), which is fluid).

To register your sidebars to accept widgets, insert this code in your functions.php file:

```
// Widget Areas //
if ( function_exists('register_sidebars') ) {
    // Primary sidebar widget
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Blog Sidebar', 'unique' ),
    'id' => 'blog-sidebar',
    'description' => __( 'The sidebar widget area for the blog.', 'unique' ),
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</li>',
    'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h2>',
) );

register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Left Sidebar', 'unique' ),
    'id' => 'left-sidebar',
    'description' => __( 'The left sidebar widget area for pages.', 'unique' ),
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="greenGradient widget-container %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</li>',
    'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title greenbar center">',
    'after_title' => '</h2>',
) );

register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Right Sidebar', 'unique' ),
    'id' => 'right-sidebar',
    'description' => __( 'The right sidebar widget area for pages.', 'unique' ),
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="redGradient widget-container %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</li>',
    'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title redbar center">',
    'after_title' => '</h2>',
) );
```

}
In this case, I have a registered sidebar for just the blog, then one each for a right sidebar and a left sidebar.

In my theme directory I have three sidebar.php files. The blog sidebar file is the default sidebar.php file. The other two are named sidebar-left.php and sidebar-right.php. Each sidebar has it's appropriate code as follows:

```
   <?php // blog widget area
        if ( is_active_sidebar( 'blog-sidebar' ) ) : ?>
        <ul>
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'blog-sidebar' ); ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; // end blog widget area ?>
```

Wrap this code inside your divs in the sidebar and be sure you change the 'blog-sidebar' name to the one for each sidebar.

Comment: Thank you for your reply HeatherFeuer. I think I've been misunderstood though. 
I know how to hardcode and register sidebars, but what I'm trying to accomplish is to let the user do that without having to write any code, but through a form in the options panel, just like Sidebar Generator allows you to do.
Problem is I can't properply include it into my theme.

Comment: Okay, I did misunderstand! So what you are trying to do is provide layout options like in the Suffusion theme?

Comment: I installed the plugin in a test site I have on my local server and I couldn't get it to work with TwentyTen and the latest version of WP. I see how it's supposed to work though. It hasn't been worked on in over two years and the license pretty much let's you do whatever you want. My recommendation would be to get that code to work and incorporate it in your theme -- giving credit to the original author of the code.

Comment: Yeah there is no licencing problems with the script and even if it's a 2 years old plugin I guess it's still the simplest solution to achieve unlimited sidebars feature inside your theme.
Finally I could get it to work and integrate it with the Options Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for function `admin_menu` and edit in that line. Just replace `__FILE__` by `sidebar-generator`.

**Interpretation**: If you use sidebar generator as a plugin, `__FILE__` means `sidebar-generator`, but if you include it in some directory of your themes, the constant `__FILE__` may change to something different (such as inc, includes... or something else)